# Get closest "1" to the left

Tags: java

I have a 2D Array:

```
        {0, 0, 1, 1, 1},
        {0, 0, 1, 1, 1},
        {0, 0, 1, 1, 1},
        {0, 1, 0, 0, 1}
```

and I am trying to see which row has the closest 1 to the left, in this case it is index 3. So we have to return 3 to console, but I don't know how to go about comparing the values, etc.
This is what I have tried so far:

```
    int array[][] = {

            {0, 0, 1, 1, 1},
            {0, 0, 1, 1, 1},
            {0, 0, 1, 1, 1},
            {0, 1, 0, 0, 1}
    };

    int count = 0;

    Map<Integer, Integer> countMap = new HashMap<>();

    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++){
            if(array[i][j] != 1){
                count++;
            }else{
                System.out.println("index of i: " + i + ", index of j:" + j + ", count: " + count);
                countMap.put(j, count);
                count = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    
    System.out.println();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try to iterate in a column wise manner and return result as soon as you encounter the first '1'. This way you don't need to spend extra computation iterating through the whole 2D matrix.

```
public class ClosestOne {
    
    public static int closestOne(int[][] a) {
        for(int i = 0; i < a[0].length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
                if(a[j][i] == 1) {
                    return j;
                }
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int array[][] = {
                {0, 0, 1, 1, 1},
                {0, 0, 1, 1, 1},
                {0, 0, 1, 1, 1},
                {0, 1, 0, 0, 1}
        };
        int closestRow = closestOne(array);
        if(closestRow == -1) {
            System.out.println("'1' is not present in matrix!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Closest '1' is in row: " + closestRow );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a HashMap is completely over-engineered here. Theoretically you do not need any kind of data structure since you calculate the values row-by-row anyways, but since you were using one, I thought I would use one, too.

Use a simple array instead of the Map, with the length of the original array (i.e. the rows). Fill that array with a number that is higher than any result can be, to be safe I used `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

```java
int[] firstIndex = new int[array.length];
//for all i in length of array:
  firstIndex[i] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

No iterate though your your 2d array like you are and overwrite the `firstIndex` if you find something that is better than the current value.

```java
//for every row
  //for ever column (col)
    if (array[row][col] == 1 && col < firstIndex[row]) {
      firstIndex[row] = col;
    }
```

Then in the end look for the minimum value in that array.

```java
int min = firstIndex[0];
for (int row = 1; row < firstIndex.length; row++) {
  min = Integer.min(min, firstIndex[row]);
}

System.out.println(min);
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have already worked out the `count` to the first 1 on each row, you just need to decide which is the lowest after completing your loop. You don't need a map to do that, just check if the current row is better than the "best so far" and if it is then update the best.
There is actually no need for a `count` variable since `j` is the same thing, and `i` is the row.

```
        int best = -1;  // Initialize to -1 which is an invalid index
        int bestCount = Integer.MAX_VALUE; // Initialize to a very bad best count.
    
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
                if (array[i][j] == 1 && j < bestCount) {
                    best = i;   // the row
                    bestCount = j; // the '1'
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Closest 1 to left in row " + best);
```